# problem with resetting window repeat clock at c++

Tags: c++, openpose

problem with resetting window while repeat clock at c++

I tried to reset the time using time, chrono. However, the code execution time continued to increase without initialization.

Hello, I'm a student at the Korea Institute of Technology. Use the translator. 
Please excuse me for speaking awkwardly.

I'm designing a program that uses the C++ OpenPose library to measure the right PC user tax.
Basically, we've completed the function of floating a pop-up to provide feedback when your right shoulder or left shoulder is crooked.
However, I would like to issue an alert after a certain second rather than a feedback that is sent in the wrong position.

1. Time should be measured when the supose function is not executed, but when the user is sitting in the wrong position. Time will be measured from the time when the supose function is executed. An event should occur if the same seat is held for 20 seconds from the wrong seat.
2. The event will occur after 20 seconds, and if the time is not initialized, it will occur as soon as it is recognized as an incorrect posture. I think it's because of when. If the library breaks from where, it ends with 0 code.

Once I've solved the time-related function, I'm going to ask you a question because I'm having a hard time completing the program. 
Thank you.

---

```
while (!userWantsToExit)
        {
 // start frame

std::shared_ptr<std::vector<UserDatum>> datumProcessed;

  if (opWrapper.waitAndPop(datumProcessed))
  {

    userWantsToExit = userOutputClass.display(datumProcessed);
    userOutputClass.printKeypoints(datumProcessed);
....

//string to int

int subShoulder = stoi(rShoulderY) - stoi(lShoulderY);

//clac keypoint values for posedata

if (50 < subShoulder || -50 > subShoulder)
 {

  if (stoi(rShoulderY) < stoi(lShoulderY)) {

    clock_t t_start, t_end;
        int time;
    t_start = clock(); //start clock
    time = t_start / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    op::log(time);
    if (time > 20) {
      t_end = clock(); //end clock
      time = (int)(t_end - t_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      cv::imshow("SUPOSE", imgLshoulderDown);
      std::string id = "hjw";
      std::string pose = "leftShoulder";
      httpRequestPose(id, pose);        
      }
    }
    else if (stoi(rShoulderY) > stoi(lShoulderY)) {
    clock_t t_start, t_end;
    int time;
    t_start = clock(); //start clock
    time = t_start / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    op::log(time);
    if (time > 20) {
      cv::imshow("SUPOSE", imgRshoulderDown);
      std::string id = "hjw";
      std::string pose = "rightShoulder";
      httpRequestPose(id, pose);

    }
    t_end = clock();
    time = (int)(t_end - t_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
     }
     else {
    clock_t t_start, t_end;
    int time;

    t_end = clock();
    time = (int)(t_end - t_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
     }
  }

 }


else {}

 //op::log("Processed datum could not be emplaced.", op::Priority::High, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, __FILE__);

}
```

---

*image

[image: enter image 1]

[image: enter image 2]

[image: enter image 3]

[image: enter image 4]

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it is very hard for me to completely understand your question. However, I was a student and not good at english (even now), i know how struggling it was to find help with google translated paragraphs. Hence, i will make a try.

As I understand, you want to trigger an alert if the shoulder keeps inclining left for more than 20 seconds (same to right incline). Is that correct?

If it is correct, I think the problem is that you keep the variable ***t_start*** inside the poseDetect function. It means that everytime the pose is detected the ***t_start*** is a new one. The value ***(t_end - t_start)*** is always 0. You should declare ***t_start*** outside of that function and use a flag to check if it is the first time. I would like to suggest with below pseudo code

```
bool isLeftIncline = false;
clock_t startLeft=clock(); //get current time

void poseDetect()
{
    if (50 < subShoulder || -50 > subShoulder){
        if (stoi(rShoulderY) < stoi(lShoulderY)){ // should is inclined to the left 
            if(!isLeftIncline){ // the first time 
                startLeft=clock(); // get the starting time
                isLeftIncline=true;
                //trigger for the first time here
            }else {  // after the first time
                clock_t current=clock();
                int timeDiff=current-startLeft;
                if(timeDiff>20){ //after 20 second with same pose
                    // issue an alert
                }

                //or trigger alert every nearly 20 seconds 
                //if(timeDiff%20<3){
                    //trigger
                //}
            }

        }else {
            // the shoulder no longer inclines to the left
            // reset isLeftIncline time
            isLeftIncline = false;
        }

        // you can apply the same for the right incline here
    }

}
```